# Does the intersection of middle third and middle half Cantor sets contain an irrational number?

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, fractals

Let $C_\frac{1}{3}$ be the middle third Cantor set, that is, the set of real numbers in the interval $[0,1]$ which can be written in base $3$ using only digits $0$ and $2$.
Likewise let $C_\frac{1}{2}$ be the set of numbers in $[0,1]$ which only have digits $0$ and $3$ in their base $4$ expansion.

Is $C_\frac{1}{3}\cap C_\frac{1}{2}\neq \varnothing$?

A brief search on the internet brought to my attention only the [Newhouse thickness criterion](https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.02023) which unfortunately does not apply in this case (thickness of $C_\frac{1}{3}$ is $1$ and thinckness of $C_\frac{1}{2}$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ so their product is less than one).

---

**UPD.** Of course there are rational numbers in the intersection, as noticed  R. van Dobben de Bruyn in his comment.

So a modified question is:

**Is there an irrational number in $C_\frac{1}{3}\cap C_\frac{1}{2}$?**

According to [https://gauss.math.yale.edu/~rwk25/openprobs/](https://gauss.math.yale.edu/%7Erwk25/openprobs/) (problem 7) this is an open question.

Comment: Aren't $0$ and $1$ in both sets? For a nontrivial example, $1/4$ is $0.02020...$ in base $3$ and $0.03333...$ in base $4$.

Comment: I think $0.03333\dots$ in base four doesn't count, just as we wouldn't count $0.09999\dots$ in base ten.

Comment: @GerryMyerson actually if you look at the construction of Cantor sets, these things are allowed. Otherwise we wouldn't get $1$ either. The Cantor set is closed, so contains the limit of the sequence of elements $0.03, 0.033, \ldots$.

Comment: In a way, this is precisely the point of the Cantor set: the continuous map $\{0,1,2\}^{\mathbf N} \to \mathbf R$ taking $(a_1,a_2,\ldots)$ to $(0.a_1a_2\ldots)_3$ is not injective (because of things like $(0.0222...)_3 = (0.1)_3$), but becomes so when you restrict to $\{0,2\}^{\mathbf N}$, giving the well-known homeomorphism $\{0,2\}^{\mathbf N} \stackrel\sim\to C$.

Comment: The Cantor sets are constructed by removing middle thirds, or halves, or whatever, not by examining expansions in base three or four or whatever, so they contain $1$. And the (base four) limit of the sequence $0.03,0.033,\dots$ is $0.1$, not $0.03333\dots$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson a real number belongs to a Cantor set "constructed by removing middle thirds" if and only if it _has an_ expansion in base 3 with only 0 and 2s. Of course it may have another expansion without this property.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn thank you. I don't want to delete this question [it is definetely not suitable for MO now] so I'll modify it soon so it becomes an open problem.

Comment: Are there any isolated rational points in $C_{1/3}\cap C_{1/2}$?  If not, use the theorem: a nonempty perfect set in $\mathbb R$ has cardinal $2^{\aleph_0}$.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_set

Comment: Up to denominators $\le 10^5$ the only rationals in $C_\frac{1}{3}\cap C_\frac{1}{2}$ are those in $A=\left\{\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{84},\frac{1}{273},\frac{64}{273},\frac{1}{1092}\right\}$ and in $1-A$. Could that be all that there is in $C_\frac{1}{3}\cap C_\frac{1}{2}\cap\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: I suppose $C_{\frac{1}{3}}\times C_{\frac{1}{2}}$ has Hausdorff dimension $>1$, so for almost every direction $e$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, a positive amount of lines $\ell$ in direction $e$ have intersection with $C_{\frac{1}{3}}\times C_{\frac{1}{2}}$ of positive Hausdorff dimension. If this holds with $e=(1,1)$ and $\ell=\{y=x\}$, then we in particular find an irrational point in $C_{\frac{1}{3}} \cap C_{\frac{1}{2}}$. So the result "should" happen in a suitable measure-theoretic sense.

Comment: @BenJohnsrude this argument applied to two non-intersecting sub-intervals [their product has haussdorff dimension 2] would suggest that they intersect.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, a result of Marstrand implies that the clause "a positive amount of lines $\ell$" can be replaced with $\pi_*^e(\mu)$-a.e. line $\ell$", where I have written $\pi^e$ for orthogonal projection in direction $e$, $\mu$ for the natural self-similar probability measure on $C_{\frac{1}{3}}\times C_{\frac{1}{2}}$, and $\pi_*^e$ for the pushforward by $\pi^e$, which avoids that problem.

Comment: @BenJohnsrude  More likely: Intersect translates $C_{1/3}+t$ with $C_{1/2}$; such translates are uncountable for $t$ in a set of positive measure.  But whether $t=0$ qualifies is not answered by this.

Comment: I extended my search to denominators up to $10^7$ and still only the 6 rationals above show up. Moreover  I explored the tree of intervals in approximations of $C_\frac{1}{3}\cap C_\frac{1}{2}$ via approximation of $C_\frac{1}{3}$ or $C_\frac{1}{2}$, that is at each step refining the one whose the next power (of 3 or 4) is smaller (so 3-4 -> 9-4 -> 9-16 -> 27-16 etc.). At each step each interval generates 0, 1 or 2 intervals at the next step. What I observed is that the total number of intervals increases steadily, which --- cont ---

Comment: --- cont --- which in itself doesn't prove anything (for example newer intervals could cluster towards the 6 known rational points, while other intervals slowly become extinct), but it seems that in fact intervals rarely become extinct and instead tend to spawn an always growing number of intervals as the steps progress. So, in conclusion, my guess is that infinitely many irrationals are contained in the limit $C_\frac{1}{3}\cap C_\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing a separate question asking if $C_\frac{1}{3}\cap C_\frac{1}{2}\cap\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,\frac{1}{2}]=\{0,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{84},\frac{1}{273},\frac{64}{273},\frac{1}{1092}\}$. This I've checked for denominators $\le 10^7$ and also for all rationals with decimal length (prefix+repetend) of at least $20$, in either base $3$ or $4$. But since it's an obvious extension of your question, I'll gladly defer to you in case you would like to post it.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch many thanks for your computations, this is very interesting. Feel free to post your conjecture as a question [this is rather far from my area of research].