Is there an irrational number which in every base, has only 2 digits appear infinitely often?
Is there any irrational number which in every base, has only 2 digits appear infinitely often? What if we just restrict to non-Liouville irrational numbers (like $\pi$), and only consider bases 3 and 4?
Context: I posted a thread about the state of ignorance of the normality of $\pi$ on Twitter, and realized I couldn't find any online discussion regarding whether it's known if there is at least one base such that $\pi$ has at least three digits which appear infinitely often (there at least seems to be a consensus that there is no particular base for which $\pi$ is known to have this property).
It seems plausible that for every irrational number, it is true that for at least one of 3 and 4, there are 3 digits which appear infinitely, and significantly more plausible if we ignore Liouville numbers (the go-to class for pathological digital expansions).
However, the open status of an analogous question for integers suggests this sort of thing is generally hard to prove.
What is known: This great paper by Greg Martin gives an elementary construction of a Liouville number which is not simply normal in any base: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0006089. This doesn't rule out the possibility that non-Liouville irrational numbers must be simply normal in at least one base, or the possibility that all irrational numbers have the weaker property of having infinitely many of all (or at least 3) digits in all bases (besides 2).

This question ( https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447007/does-the-intersection-of-middle-third-and-middle-half-cantor-sets-contain-an-irr ) is a stronger form of your second question, and it seems that question is open.

@AnuragSahay One major difference is that the question you link to requires that every digit in base $3$ be in ${0,2}$ and every digit in base $4$ be in ${0,3}$ (and apparently there are even very few rationals satisfying this), whereas this question on bases $3$ and $4$ requires every digit after a certain point (so now it's much easier to find many rationals meeting the criterion).

@Gro-Tsen Great point! I missed that. Still, it suggests to me that the questions are out of reach. On the other hand, I wonder if the literature on the Newhouse gap lemma could be used to say something about the following question: is there an irrational number for which the base-$3$ expansion has at most $2$ digits appearing infinitely often while the base-$5$ expansion has at most $4$ digits appearing infinitely often?

The reason I wonder if the latter question is accessible is because (unless I messed up some calculations) the product of the thicknesses of the middle cantor sets $C_{1/3}$ and $C_{1/5}$ is $2$ which is well over what one needs to guarantee that $C_{1/3} \cap C_{1/5}$ is non-empty (though, of course, the intersection could be entirely rational).

The fact that only two digits occur infinitely often in bases $b, b^2, b^3,\dots$ implies that the base $b$ expansion is a zero entropy sequence. This fact might be helpful.

My previous comment is slightly inaccurate: I confused $C_{1/5}$ with the subset of $[0,1]$ which has no digit equal to $3$ in its base-$5$ expansion. In any case, the latter set has the same Newhouse thickness as $C_{1/5}$, so the rest of my comment still applies.
